# calculated field using if and or in ms-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF(
    [dbo.tblx.Category] = 'WS' OR [dbo.tblx.Category] = 'SEM', 
    0, 
    [dbo.tblx.Tonnes] * [dbo.tblx.Grade] / 1000
)
```

this returns the entire text and not the "calculation"

can someone help me...what am I doing wrong?

i tried

```
CASE WHEN dbo.tblx.Category = 'WS' OR dbo.tblx.Category = 'SEM' THEN 0
     ELSE  dbo.tblx.Tonnes * dbo.tblx.Grade / 1000 
END AS Metal
```

Do perhaps insert something before "CASE WHEN"? it is not running

Comment: WS is the name of a column in a table or do you mean string 'WS'?

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken here but... is this syntax not invalid in SQL Server? I thought perhaps it might be something I'm just not familiar with, similar to an `IIF`, but my SSMS is having none of it.

Comment: Do you want it into a query (select ....) or do you want to add a computed column into a table?

Comment: it is a computed column into a table

Comment: can you post the entire code

Comment: "this returns the entire text and not the "calculation"" there is no text in your sample so can you please post more code

Comment: It returns the formula, not an error message...removes the '' on the WS and SEM strings...

Comment: What it's the name of the table?

Comment: its a query table, so e.g tblVWxy

Comment: the case you tried is valid. There must be some other part in your code that is wrong. But we cannot help you because you refuse to show the code

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you are trying to create a computed column, using value from other table.
I think in this case you have to use a User Defined function in the formula for computed column.  If you give more information I can try to write some code for you.

Instead, if you just want to add a column in a query you can use:

```
CASE WHEN dbo.tblx.Category = 'WS' OR dbo.tblPTx.Category = 'SEM' THEN 0
   ELSE  dbo.tblx.Tonnes * dbo.tblx.Grade / 1000 END AS NAME_OF_YOUR_NEW_COLUMN
```

Comment: "unable to parse expression"

Comment: I think to help us to help you, you should post some sample data, view and/or tables code, etc.  as suggest StackOverflow

Comment: you should format in a readable way and add it in the question, pls

Comment: Category Tonnes Grade Metal_kg 
SEM 7,659  222  0 
LG 5,606  316  1,771 
MG 20,554  414  8,509 
WS 167,506  69  0 
  There are four columns, Category, Tonnes, Grade while the Metal_kg should be calculated. There are four rows, SEM and WS should return 0, while LG and MG should return a Tonnes*Grade. Trying to add a table but failing...

Comment: Category
SEM;
LG;
MG;
WS;
Tonnes
7,659; 
5,606;
20,554;
167,506; 
Grade
222;
316; 
414;
69;
Metal_kg
0;
1,771; 
8,509 ;
0

Comment: Please edit your question and put this data in your question it is to hard to read it here

Comment: anyway I think you can't write [dbo.tblx.Category] . You should ues [dbo].[tblx].[Category] or simply dbo.tblx.Category.  The same for the others... Try now my answer

Comment: I have a table with four columns, Category, Tonnes and Grade, I would like to have a fourth calculated column called Metal. There are four categories with WS, LG, MG and SEM. The Metal column should calculate (Tonnes*Grade)/1000 if Categories is not WS or SEM, if it is, should return '0'.

Comment: @Uno Please STOP putting important info in comments. Edit you question and put this info in you question

Comment: @GuidoG   I stop to write him, I suppose he/she/it is just joking.  Ina few time I think I'm going to delete my answer.

Comment: @etsa Yes maybe you are right. The question also not makes much sense either this might be a bogus question

Comment: Oh my! I am new at this...@Uno Please STOP putting important info in comments. Edit you question and put this info in you question..i understand now only what you mean, thought you meant it in the comments.

Answer (score -3):

**Update**

```
DECLARE @myvar INT;
SET @myvar = CASE WHEN ([dbo.tblx.Category] = WS OR [dbo.tblPTx.Category] = SEM) THEN 0 
                  ELSE  [dbo.tblx.Tonnes] * [dbo.tblx.Grade] / 1000 
             END
```

Comment: Downvote and no comment? Whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: Did you try running this? It seems like you've got your wires crossed in regards to the syntax for `IF` and `CASE`.

Comment: No, but it should give an idea of what I mean. What would you expect? Ready to use code when the source is already invalid?

Comment: Uhhh.... yes? What do you think the point of this website is? People come here with questions, invalid code, etc, and the community provides working solutions to their issues. Not only is the syntax in your answer completely wrong, you've also asked OP to "try it" without even testing it yourself. You received downvotes because you provided a *guess* as an answer, and it isn't even valid SQL.

Comment: Uhhh.... No? I can just write some pseudo code to bring over the idea and solve the issue. In most cases that would be perfectly fine. Its kinda lazy if you expect copy/paste code.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with this website a bit more. And lets not be confused here... you and I both know that this answer is *not* pseudo-code, by any stretch of the imagination  (it's actually longer than what would be the *correct* syntax). You're simply defending an entirely incorrect answer.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree. I've seen tons of pseudo or not directly working code here that did provide a accepted answer. Anyway, my effort is voted down so why should I put more time in this?

Comment: it does not work, returns "the entire text''...but thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "the entire text''